# Python subprocess returns wrong exit code

Tags: python, subprocess, exit-code

I wrote a script to launch a number of processes (simple unit tests) to run in parallel. It will do `N` jobs with `num_workers` parallel processes at a time.

My first implementation ran the processes in batches of `num_workers` and seemed to be working fine (I used the `false` command here to test the behavior)

```
import subprocess

errors = 0
num_workers = 10
N = 100
i = 0

while i < N:
    processes = []
    for j in range(i, min(i+num_workers, N)):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['false'])
        processes.append(p)

    [p.wait() for p in processes]
    exit_codes = [p.returncode for p in processes]

    errors += sum(int(e != 0) for e in exit_codes)
    i += num_workers

print(f"There were {errors}/{N} errors")
```

However, the tests do not take equal amounts of time so I was sometimes waiting for a slow test to finish. Thus I rewrote it to keep assigning tasks as they finished

```
import subprocess
import os


errors = 0
num_workers = 40
N = 100
assigned = 0
completed = 0
processes = set()

while completed < N:
    if assigned < N:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['false'])
        processes.add((assigned, p))
        assigned += 1
    if len(processes) >= num_workers or assigned == N:
        os.wait()

    for i, p in frozenset(processes):
        if p.poll() is not None:
            completed += 1
            processes.remove((i, p))
            err = p.returncode
            print(i, err)
            if err != 0:
                errors += 1

print(f"There were {errors}/{N} errors")
```

However this produces wrong results for the last few processes. For instance, in the example above it produces 98/100 errors instead of 100. I checked and this has nothing to do with concurrency; the 2 latest jobs were returning with exit code 0 for some reason.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Consider using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of managing your own parallel processes.

Comment: @ndmeiri What race condition? Only the main thread reads/writes the `errors` variable.

Comment: Not a race condition; `os.wait()` clobbers the return code for `poll()`.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Good eye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `os.wait()`. It doesn't only wait for a child process to exit: it also returns the pid and "exit status indication" of that child, as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) says. This requires waiting until the child process has terminated; but once the child has terminated, its return code is no longer available for `poll`. Here's a simple test to reproduce the problem:

#### false_runner.py

```
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['false'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
pid, retcode = os.wait()
print("From os.wait: {}".format(retcode))
print("From popen object before poll: {}".format(p.returncode))
p.poll()
print("From popen object after poll: {}".format(p.returncode))
```

#### output

```
njv@organon:~/tmp$ python false_runner.py
From os.wait: 256
From Popen object before poll: None
From Popen object after poll: 0
```

[The source code for `_internal_poll`, called by `Popen.poll`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/subprocess.py#L1366), makes it clear what's happening here: when `Popen` tries to call `_waitpid` on its child process's pid, it gets `ChildProcessError: [Errno 10] No child processes`, and assigns itself a `returncode` of 0, because there's no way to determine the child process's return code at this point.

The reason this happens only for the last couple of subprocesses in your example is because `os.wait` is only getting called for the `or assigned == N` case, and only once or twice, because your subprocess is so fast. If you slow it down a bit, you'll get more random behavior.

As for a fix: I'd probably just replace `os.wait()` with a sleep.